# Template Literals no-useless-concat

Tags: eslint, template-literals

I'm curious about the eslint warning "no-useless-concat".
From other stackoverflow questions I saw using template-literals is the preferred method of concatenating strings dynamically, in order to not get such eslint warnings.

I want to define a css-class based upon a condition (`liked` is a boolean):

```js
const heartClass = `fa fa-heart${liked ? "" : "-o"}`;
```

While compiling (using React) I still get the following warning:

```
WARNING in src\components\Like.jsx
  Line 6:55:  Unexpected string concatenation of literals  no-useless-concat
```

What am I doing wrong - Why do I still get the `no-useless-concat` warning?

Kind Regards
Andreas

Comment: The line of code you are showing does not produce that error. Look carefully, the error is on line nr. 6. in Like.jsx. How does that line look like?

Comment: Thanks for the input. It seems a bit weird to me, that the error occurs on line 6. As you can see in the picture the only known string concatenation to me is on line 4:
https://prnt.sc/26fbegd